# separating the complex and real roots of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose that we have a known polynomial $P(x)$ with real coefficients $a_i$. We do not want to calculate its roots. Is there a way to find a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that it has all the only complex roots of $P(x)$? We have to construct $Q(x)$ only by means of the coefficients $a_i$. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $P(x)=Q(x)\cdot R(x)$?

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen, Sorry, I edited the question. It is better understood.

Comment: Any method for doing this will imply that you can solve arbitrary polynomials over the reals. Given $p(x)$, the polynomial $p^2+(x-x_0)^2$ has one or no real roots: one root (ignoring multiplicity) if $x_0$ is a root of $p$ and no roots otherwise. Applying your hoped-for method for constructing $Q$ to this polynomial, you have that $Q=p^2+(x-x_0)^2$ iff $x_0$ is not a root of $p$. So I think that you will not get an easy answer to this question.

Comment: @ Hank Scorpio, Yes, I thought about it and unfortunately you are correct. Thanks